# Como validar que una fecha este dentro de un rango de fechas con javascript y jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero validar si una fecha esta dentro de un rango mediante de javascript

Por ejemplo

```
    const fechaInicio=new Date('2020-01-01');
    const fechaFin=new Date('2020-01-30');
    const fechaValidar=new Date('2020-01-10');
```

Quisiera generar una funcion para reutilizar la misma funcion en varias partes del codigo

```
  function validarFechaEnRango(fechaInicio,fechaFin,fechaValidar){
    //codigo retorna booleano si fechaValidar esta dentro del rango de fecha.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes devolver simplementa la evaluación de la condición

```javascript
function validarFechaEnRango(inicio,fin,fecha){
    return inicio.valueOf() <= fecha.valueOf() && fecha.valueOf() <= fin.valueOf();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer una validación entre rangos de fecha yo convertiría las fechas en milisegundos y haria la validación de la siguiente forma:

```
const fechaInicio=new Date('2020-01-01');
const fechaFin=new Date('2020-01-30');
const fechaValidar=new Date('2020-01-10');

function validarFechaEnRango(fechaInicio,fechaFin,fechaValidar){

    const fechaInicioMs = fechaInicio.getTime();
    const fechaFinMs = fechaFin.getTime();
    const fechaValidarMs = fechaValidar.getTime();

    if(fechaValidarMs >= fechaInicioMs && fechaValidarMs <= fechaFinMs){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```